# Unexpected T_BOOLEAN_OR in email script

Tags: php, forms, http-post

I wrote a script to send the contents of a contact form (first name, last name and email address) to the website owner.  However, when I press the Submit button on my form the error:

```
Unexpected T_BOOLEAN_OR
```

is given.  Here's the snippet of code near the line number referenced:

```
function died($error) {  

echo "We are very sorry, but there were error(s) found with the form you submitted. ";   
echo "These errors appear below.<br /><br />";         
echo $error."<br /><br />";         
echo "Please go back and fix these errors.<br /><br />";        
die();     }           
// validation expected data exists    
if(!isset($_POST['first_name']) ||         
!isset($_POST['last_name']) ||        
!isset($_POST['email'])) || {    
died('We are sorry, but there appears to be a problem with the form you submitted.'); 
}
```

Thanks much for your help:)

Comment: Is this your normal code indenting style?  If so, you should probably adopt the standard procedure of indenting lines inside curlies and half-indenting lines inside multi-line if statements, as these two steps would have made your error much more visible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
!isset($_POST['email'])) || {     <-- there's your problem
```